# anchor hash ignores other url parameters

Tags: html, url, hash, anchor

I have footnotes in page as:

```
<a href="#footnote">footnote</a>.
```

however if current location of the page is

```
www.domain.com/?q=something,
```

the resulting url of footnote is 
not `www.domain.com/?q=something#footnote`, 
but `www.domain.com/#footnote`

so is absolute url usage is the only solution for above, or there some techniques to come over this?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried that in Chrome and it worked fine.  By default, a browser will assume it's a relative URL (unless the format indicates otherwise).

Comment: I also hava the chrome result, which ignores url parameters... is there a special format for this?

Comment: I figured out... it was the wrong <base href=""> in the head of the page... thanks

Answer (score 0):

From what you're posting here, I hardly see how it can fail. If you provided some more info, maybe people can help.

Answer (score 0):

But it will happen at IE.

You can try this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $body = (window.opera) ? (document.compatMode == "CSS1Compat" ? $('html') : $('body')) : $('html,body');
    $body.animate({scrollTop: jQuery('.youcalss').offset().top}, 1000);
})
```